# [Vue warn]: Failed to generate render function:

Tags: vue.js

I have this strange error which I cannot figure out.

I am using the latest VueJS, pulled from the official CDN with:

`<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>`

[image]

Specified line looks like below:

[image]

Did anyone experienced this? Is it a `VueJS` problem?

Later edit:

I believe the error is here:

```
    attrs: {
        "type": "text",
        "name": "phone",
        "value": "",
        "id": "phone",
        "phone_number":
    }
```

the v-bind on the "phone_number" field didn't work as expected for some reason.

Removed the `:phone_number="phone_number"` and wrote it again, and it just worked.

Comment: How are you using it, A little bit of code may help.

Comment: I have 525 lines of code. Not sure what should I show ... however that part with `console.error` is a vuejs code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error was in fact as you pointed in there

```
attrs: {
    "type": "text",
    "name": "phone",
    "value": "",
    "id": "phone",
    "phone_number":
}
```

"phone_number": here isn't set to anything, that's why Vue squacked and threw an error saying that the } was unexpected.

Comment: I have the same problem and still not figure it out, i tried many many things but nothing yet, maybe you have another shoot!?

Comment: Well for the context of this question, this was the problem that the phone number did not have any value, if you have a similar problem that you can't figure out, you probably should ask a new question and include your code so that others could actually help you.

Comment: Thanks @OmarTarek, i fix my problem, so for future, my error was in my Laravel Blade template passing null in ternary operator.

was 
`:available-salespeople="{{$forecourt ? collect($forecourt->salespeopleSelect) : null }}"` 

To fix i didi the else return a empty object 

`:available-salespeople="{{$forecourt ? collect($forecourt->salespeopleSelect) : json_encode([])}}"`

Answer (score 12):

If you are using Laravel and you are passing data in a Blade template like this:

```
<your-component :value="{{ $myValue }}"></your-component>
```

It may be that `$myValue` is null and therefore the error occurs.

A simple way to fix this is to use `json_encode` before passing values as an attribute to the component:

```
<your-component :value="{{ json_encode($myValue) }}"></your-component>
```

Comment: Thanks!
I myself only wanted to pass strings, so simply removing the colon from the props got the job done.

Comment: also if you are using the laravel package `renatomarinho/laravel-page-speed` simply remove ```RenatoMarinho\LaravelPageSpeed\Middleware\InlineCss::class``` from `kernel`

Comment: In my case it was JavaScript variables passed using a named slot in a blade template: in Chrome it is acceptable but in IE11 it triggered an error. `<template v-slot:validationTrigger="{ validate, validationError }">...</template>`

Answer (score 0):

This is the sort of thing which makes coding in client script 10x slower than on the server.  The question is asking about a specific problem, but a more general question is ... how on earth do you track down an error like this in hundreds of lines of HTML and JavaScript?

In my case, the problem was in this line:

```
<div class="woBuyCheckoutError">{{ Please correct the errors below for your invoice contact details }}</div>
```

You'll notice I foolishly forgot to remove the {{ }} brackets, so Vue thought that this was a call to a function.  MVC would have highlighted this in a nano-second, but I've just spent half an hour trying to track it down.

My advice: try deleting or commenting out large chunks of code until you can find a block containing the syntax error, then reinstate them bit by bit until you find the culprit.  Good luck!